# Knock out js - Binding values based on the option selected in the select control

Tags: javascript, json, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm working with knock out js

I'm binding the values of the control as follows,

Html,

```
<html>
    <select id ="eg" data-bind:"value:name().nationality.gender.Id"/>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <options>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>   
</html>
```

JavaScipt,

```
function viewmodel(objservermodel)
{
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS($.parseJSON(objservermodel));
}
```

json comes like this,

```
   {"nationality":[{"gender":{"Id":"1"}}]}
```

but when i refer to it as "data-bind:"value:name().nationality.gender.Id""

it says Id is undefined,

I also tried,

```
   "value: name().nationality[0].gender.Id" or "value: name().nationality()[0].gender().Id"
```

I only got console error message as,

```
     Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
     gender undefined
     Bindings value:  value:value: name().nationality[0].gender.Id
```

Could someone tell me how to exactly bind to Id,

Id value should be binded based on the option selected in the select control.

I tried several, still didn't arrive at the solution,

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: create example in jsfiddle

Comment: select is not binded like this.please take a look al [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single select list binds to an observable array like this:

**Javascript:**

```
function viewmodel(objservermodel)
{  
    var parseJson = function(){
        ......//parse nationalities json array
    }

    self.nationalities = ko.observableArray(parseJson()); //js array with all parsed nationalities from incoming json
    self.selectedNationality = ko.observable(); //this gives you the current selected nationality object


}



ko.applyBindings($("#foo")[0], viewmodel); //apply bindings!!!
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="foo">
<select id ="eg" data-bind:"options: nationalities, value: selectedNationality"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out,

```
  data-bind:"value:name().nationality()[0].gender.Id"
```

and the values got updated with each change in the options selected in the select control.

This worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since JSON returned nationality as array object,

I have to bind it as,

```
 data-bind:"value:name().nationality()[0].gender.Id" 

 data-bind:"value:name().nationality()[1].gender.Id" 

 data-bind:"value:name().nationality()[2].gender.Id"
```

and so on.

Hence worked out.